# Add logstash configuration to PCF user created service

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, cloud-foundry, elk, pcf

I've created a user-created service in PCF with syslog-drain-url connected to kibana and I want to add a configuration file to parse multiline log messages. How can I do it? Can I just add a config file in my application and use some name convention to make it work?

Comment: What are you trying to configure with the file exactly? The user provided service with the log drain URL, when bound to an app, is read by the platform, which then automatically takes the logs and metrics output by your app and sends them to the URL. That's it though. There's no option to configure that process beyond the URL, at least from the platform's point of view.

Comment: I want to configure multiline log messages because now it's break messages by \n and I can not find stack trace in kibana. I know it's possible to configure logstash on app side for filebeat, so I suppose it should be a similar option for user-created service

Comment: There is nothing you can do on the platform side to configure how it sends logs. It will send each line as a separate message. This is the workaround I've seen most people use: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/loggregator-release/blob/develop/docs/java-multi-line-work-around.md.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try to use this workaround.